# How to shorten URL address in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat

I have a question about shortening of URL address when working with Java Servlets. I need to shorten address e.g. **www.IPaddress.com:8181/JSP/Index.jsp** just to **www.IPaddress.com** without port number (8181) and .jsp extension. Is it even possible to do something like this? I developed this Servlet application in Eclipse IDE and I am working with Apache Tomcat 8.

Comment: If the port is not specified, it's assumed to be 80

Comment: @MauricePerry Yeah, I was affraid that there will be this issue, that if the port is not present in a URL address that 8080 port is taken automatically. But it would be great if there was some way how to set port to 8181 somewhere in the web.xml or somewhere else and shorten a URL address just to www.example.com

Comment: It's 80, not 8080, and the only way I can think of would be to place a reverse-proxy in front of your server.

Comment: you should be able to use apache or some other server and rewrite the urls its been a while and I dont remember how to do it exactly but that is something you could look into

Comment: As John Kane writes, it's port 80 for the http protocol and port 443 for the https. If your server runs on a different port, the port **must** be specified. The usual way to handle this is to set up an http server in front of your app server, and configure it as a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html). [Here](https://rvdb.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/reverse-proxying-tomcat-webapps-behind-apache/) is a quite nice (although slightly obsolete) guide how to do that with Tomcat and Apache HTTPD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this kind of mapping can be achieve by creating a virtual host in  some web server like apache and map it to redirect different host based on the requirement.

Using only tomcat I tried below steps and achieve your requirement .

1. Modify your tomcat's server.xml to remove the context path as blank for the host like below

   `<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
     <Context path="" docBase="PATH_OF_YOUR_TOMCAT/webapps/YOU_APPLICATION_NAME"/>`
2. You have to run your tomcat using port 80 to remove the port from URL. So you can either change the existing port in your server.xml to 80 or add one more connector in your tomcat's server.xml with port 80. i.e in this case your tomcat will listen to both 8181 and 80. Make sure you restart tomcat using admin as port 80 is a privilege port.

   ```
   <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443" />
   ```

   `<Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443" />`

> After following above 2 steps You should be able to access your application using 
>   http://localhost/index.jsp

3. Now You can use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to hide the JSP extension in both request and response or can use servlet mapping like below

   `<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>some.jsp</jsp-file>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/somelink</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>`

You can also put your index.jsp as a welcome file list in web.xml like below

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

> Now You should be able to access your application using below as per
>   your requirement  http://localhost